# A "should never get here" line in a method

Tags: c, function

I find myself writing functions with this line and I always feel a little bad about myself when doing it. Do other people do this? Is it bad practice?

```
void f()
{
    while(true) {
    // ...
    if(condition)
        return;
    }

    //should not get here
    assert(0);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for not using `if(condition)
        break;` and then returning from the end of the function?

Comment: In your examle it serves no purpose other than to indicate to future maintainers that the endless loop with return was intentional.  It is not a compelling example however, because `do{ //... } while( condition) ;` would serve the same purpose.  If coding style and "feeling bad" is your concern, I'd be more troubled by returning from the middle of a function rather then _only_ then end, where your poor future maintainer might expect it.  `assert`s are removed from non-debug code in any event, so in this case there is no redundancy.  Otherwise your optimizer might warn of unreachable code.

Comment: Code such as this that "protects" against something that _cannot_ happen serves no purpose.  An assert to protect against something that _should not_ happen, but could given invalid input is reasonable.  This is not such an example.  In any case you would generally test preconditions for input at the start.  It is done; often for poor reasons.  It sometimes serves a purpose to protect against errors introduced during maintenance - often by different and less experienced developers who may not fully understand the code they are maintaining.

Comment: @Clifford Too bad your good lengthy comments were too late for this closed question to form an answer.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. This is a _function_.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how critical it is that the code never get to that point.

If I have code that absolutely can't be allowed to fail, I frequently put in checks for non-allowable conditions that shouldn't be able to happen.

If it's a case/switch statement, I always put in a default with an error handler even though it should never be able to get there.

Comment: Good point regarding unused default case (or equally an unused else after a series of else-if).  These are examples of where this _is_ good practice.  The example in the question is a poor example because there are better ways to structure the function that avoid the more insidious practice of returning from the middle of a function or breaking from the middle of a loop.

Comment: @Clifford Yeah, I can;'t really see a reason to do anything odd after a "while(true)" loop. If that's broken, none of the code can be trusted at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Do other people do this? Is it bad practice?

Yes, other coders do this.  No, it not not *bad* practice, just weaker than alternatives.

---

The reason it is weak is reflected in this question.  It draws unnecessary attention to a coding style that has other good alternatives.  Why code in a manner that *looks* wrong?  Even if OK here, it encourages reviewers to become nonchalant about seeing other loops without a clear exit - that in itself is not good.

```
void f() {
  while(true) {
    // ...
    if(condition) {
      break;
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

If there is a good reason to code in OP's exceptional style, it deserves comments to explain why to not waste time of reviewers, maintainers or anyone reading the code.

```
void f() {
  while(true) {
    // ...
    if(condition) {
      // Clear documentation why the above layout does not work
      return;
    }
    // ...
  }
  //should not get here
  assert(0);
}
```

Comment: Or in this case `do{ //... } while( condition) ;`.

Comment: @Clifford That too is a possibility.  I read that OP wants to ask about returning from some place not at the beginning/end of the loop.  Otherwise `while, do, for` would suffice.

Comment: True, but in his original example, there is no indication of elided code after the return.  My point is that better coding practices and clear thinking can both avoid the unreachable code and the need for either return or break from a loop -both of which are contrary to a number of common coding standards. Changing to `if( !condition) { //...}`  will avoid the return/break in your example also - at no cost to complexity or clarity - the second elided block is made explicitly conditional by reversing the condition.

Comment: @Clifford I concluded the question was the loop exit was of some arbitrary middle point..A question about an `if() return` at the end of the loop only, from a 1300 rep user, did not seem as likely as a more general one.Only teachers & lawyers ask perfect questions (they know the answer beforehand), the rest of us dance around about and try to deduce the real question.  You could be right about OP's intent though - using a `do { ... } while (!condition);` is a good approach.  Note that `do {...} while (condition);` obliges that `condition` is scoped outside the loop - sometimes a minor bump.